# freeboard datasource plugin

Tags: json, plugins, datasource, freeboard

I am creating a new Datasource plugin - JSON with query parameters.

In it, I would like to show a dropdown, the users can select the value and it will update the data source URL.

The values of the dropdown should be populated before the plugin is loaded. Its working if I hardcode the values but if I try them from the DB (via ajax or getJSON), its not showing the values. The reason being the plugin UI is being shown before the values are obtained.

How can I delay showing of UI until I get the values back ?

Thanks

Comment: Show us code be code be core asking about anything else. Consult this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before proceeding.

Comment: Can you share produced datasource plugin, even better with steps that you conducted? I'm trying to rescue already made plugin proposed by fiware, but came across difficulties.